# shared_preferences load data

Tags: flutter, dart

first time with flutter,
we have to file user.dart and opt_form.dart, in user.dart i store data in list[] like this:

```
storeData(data) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //setState(() {
  prefs.setStringList('data_user', [data]);
  //});
}
```

in the second page opt_form.dart we try to get the list

```
var _value = [''];

void loadData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   setState(() {
     final key = 'data_user';
     _value = prefs.getStringList(key) ?? [];
   });
}
```

in the button press()

```
DefaultButton(
        text: "Valider",
        press: () async {
          loadData();
          print(_value);
        },
      )
```

the print(_value) return in the first click [] and data in the second ? any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just your need add `await` before `loadData()` method like this:

```
DefaultButton(
        text: "Valider",
        press: () async {
          await loadData();
          print(_value);
        },
      )
```

Comment: thank osama, but 'await' applied to 'void', which is not a 'Future'

Comment: i change  var _value = ['']; to List<String> _value = List(7); and is work

Comment: if you add await before laodData() method , Then you need to change the 'void' to 'Future' or remove 'void' , you are welcome

Comment: change var _value = ['']; to List<String> _value = List(7); does not affect anything